# How to add data into ArrayList in onCreateView Method (View Pager)?

Tags: android, arraylist, sms, smsmanager

I am making an application for SMS. I have used fragment and I initialize all my component in onCreateView now the problem is, I want to add some data to the Array List using a method which should be call when an SMS come. So where I have to call my method to add data to the Array List.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your codes in fragment life cycle or u can call a function in onCreateView and inside the function u can find your components and can write your codes.